# GCC use headers under a different name at preprocessing time

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to, when preprocessing occurs, request gcc (or cpp?) to link header file imports in code to different headers? For example, if I have a large codebase which uses a lot of `#import <GL/gl.h>`, while on the system I'm compiling on OpenGL headers reside in `#import <OpenGL/gl.h>`, could I request the preprocessor to link all import requests in GL to OpenGL?
**Edit**: The point is not to edit the source code. Like if hypothetically the only file you had access to was the Makefile.

Comment: If your filesystem supports symlinks, wouldn't it be easier to just have `GL` link to `OpenGL`? I could create the symlink locally to your project so that not to pollute system-wide directories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can preprocess include or import names. Technique is called "computed includes" and documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Computed-Includes.html)

```
 #define GL_H "GL/gl.h"
 ...
 #include GL_H
```

Behavior of `#import` in such cases must be identical to `#include`.